# Run AsynkTask multiple time not work

Tags: java, android

this is my code. and when i select multiple "swdetails" only last one working. others set text not work. i'm new to android development. looking for some helps.

```
 swdetails = getArguments().getBooleanArray("service");
    final String s = getArguments().getString("snote");
    cdata = getArguments().getStringArray("cdata");

    grdm = (GridLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.setmain);
    if (swdetails[0]) {
        GridLayout grdv = (GridLayout) View.inflate(
                rootView.getContext(),
                R.layout.grdcctv, null);
        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute("cctvid", "rcisl_clients_cctv");
        finalResult = (EditText) grdv
                .findViewById(R.id.txtcctv);
        grdm.addView(grdv);
    }
    if (swdetails[1]) {
        GridLayout grdv = (GridLayout) View.inflate(
                rootView.getContext(),
                R.layout.grdsolar, null);
        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute("solarid", "rcisl_clients_solar");
        finalResult = (EditText) grdv
                .findViewById(R.id.txtsolarid);
        grdm.addView(grdv);
    }

    if (swdetails[2]) {
        GridLayout grdv = (GridLayout) View.inflate(
                rootView.getContext(),
                R.layout.grdintercom, null);

        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        runner.execute("intercomid", "rcisl_clients_intercom");
        finalResult = (EditText) grdv
                .findViewById(R.id.txtintercomid);
        grdm.addView(grdv);
    }
```

[there is screen shot what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K3i7.jpg)

Comment: i think  you have used check boxes or list where your selecting multiples items **swdetails** should be a array where it stores ur selection.

Now in this condition it stores only the last one you have selected in multiple choices

Comment: no its store all array details. and "grdv" gridlayout is adding to "grdm" gridlayout. its success but `finalResult = (EditText) grdv
                .findViewById(R.id.txtintercomid);' not working all three time. only work with last swdetails.

Comment: There is mistake 
**grdm.addView(grdv);** here each time **GridLayout** is updating the list now you should have to make strategy to add all views in layout 

all conditions are working fine each condition is updating gridlayout

Comment: haven't idea to do it. i'm staked

Comment: this is my project [link](https://github.com/lakmallz/CRM)